# Convert raw query to laravel eloquent with sum function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
DB::SELECT(
            "SELECT SUM(carts.quantity) as couuntq, carts.productid, products.name, products.name, products.price,products.gallary FROM carts,products  
            WHERE 
            carts.productid = products.id AND
            carts.userid = ".$userid ."
            GROUP BY carts.productid
            order by carts.productid"
)
```

> I converted but not working with sum function

```
DB::table('carts')
        ->join('products','carts.productid','products.id')
        ->select('carts.quantity','carts.productid', 'products.name', 'products.name', 'products.price','products.gallary')
        ->where('carts.userid',$userid)
        ->groupBy('carts.productid')
        ->orderBy('carts.productid')
        ->sum('carts.quantity')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
add your sum aggregate method in `raw` along with your other required column names

```
DB::table('carts')
    ->join('products','carts.productid','=','products.id')
    ->Select(DB::raw('SUM(carts.quantity) as couuntq'), 'carts.productid', 'products.name', 'products.price', 'products.gallary')
    ->where('carts.productid','products.id')
    ->where('carts.userid',$userid)
    ->GroupBy('carts.productid')
    ->orderBy('carts.productid', 'asc')
    ->get();
```